# plotly.js: show only the first x-axis ticklabel

Tags: plotly

In a plotly.js time series, I would like to show only the first timestamp as a ticklabel. The rest of the ticklabels should not be displayed.

Even cooler would be, to display ticklabels for the first and the middle timestamp. By "middle", I mean the timestamp in the middle of the timestamps array.

Answer (score 2):

I think [the options about `tickvals`and `ticktext`](https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/#enumerated-ticks-with-tickvals-and-ticktext) could be the good solution for your problem.

```
var layout = {
    title: 'Title of the graph',
    xaxis: {
        tickvals : ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01'],
        ticktext : ['First', 'Midlle', 'End']
    },
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

In this example, by setting the respectively the `tickvals` and the `ticktext` to what you want to display (or not), you should have something working pretty good.